# Appending a line of text in a Text_Box in ruby shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

How do you append a line of text in a Text_Box in ruby shoes? I can see no way of doing this. Currently I am writing to a text file then opening that text file to get newly appended content.

Comment: could you be a little more specific? I don't see a Text_Box element in Shoes' documentation.  Maybe paste in the code you are using today for reference.  But I'm pretty sure you can just @textbox.text = @textbox.text + "\nNew Text"

Comment: Hmm I'll have to try that tomorrow. I just had a total duh ruby moment.

Answer (score 1):

here two ways, one with the initialisation and one after

```
Shoes.app :width => 300, :height => 450 do
  @text = edit_box :width => 1.0, :height => 400, :text =>'test'
  @text.text = "test2"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 forms of Text_Box:

```
banner, a 48 pixel font.
title, a 34 pixel font.
subtitle, a 26 pixel font.
tagline, an 18 pixel font.
caption, a 14 pixel font.
para, a 12 pixel font.
inscription, a 10 pixel font.
```

To create a Text_Box of 12 pixel font you need to do that:

```
Shoes.app do
   @text_box_example = para "Some text \n"
   #To append line:
   @text_box_example.replace @text_box_example + "New line of text\n"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late but you can do it like this:

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do            
background "#EFC"
flow :width=>'100%', :margin=>10 do
    stack do
        title "Green shoes append example"
    end

    @j=edit_box("Data")

    stack :width=>150 do
        b=button "Click me"
        b.click{
        @j.text=  "#{@j.text} New line of text\n"
        }

    end
    end
 end
```

j is the name of the edit_box.